# Subcaption incompatible with babel-farsi

Tags: subcaption, incompatibility, persian

I am trying to use some farsi words in my text. I also have to use subcaption for my pics. But I am getting the following error:

! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly(caption) in compatibility mode.See the caption package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{document}

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,                               
DIV=calc,                           
parskip=half,version=first,             % Absatzformatierung s. scrguide 
.1
headsepline,                    
numbers=noenddot
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[includehead=false, includefoot=false, paperheight=240mm, 
paperwidth=170mm, 
twoside=true, left=25mm, right=20mm, 
top=35mm, 
bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}   
\clearscrplain
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ofoot{}
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman,greek,farsi]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage[format=plain, font=small, font=it, labelfont=it,       labelfont=small,
width=12.5cm, indention=.5cm]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[authordate-trad,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}



\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}


Some Text. \\
Greek \textgreek{μέθοδος}.\\
Farsi \FR{روش}.

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You solve this issue by opening an issue at gitlab [1], waiting for an adaption of the `caption` package bundle to the `farsi` babel package, and by reviewing this adaption so the maintainer of the `caption` package bundle can release this adaption in all conscience to CTAN. BTW: I'm the maintainer and try to make the adaption tomorrow. Please hold the line...  [1] https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues

Comment: P.S.: I just did the 1st step for you: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/35

Comment: @Axel: Thank you for the comments! I am looking forward to your solution.

Comment: A test version of the `caption` package bundle which should solve this issue is available here: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/tree/3.3/tex

Comment: @Axel: Thanks for the new package bundle. I replaced the bundle. But now I get other sorts of errors: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.

Comment: ... ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.

Comment: ...l.9 <meta content="GitLab" property="og:site_
name">

Comment: It seems there was a problem saving the files, they seem to have HTML content and not LaTeX content. You need to click every file separately and then click the "Download" button.